# Why i have to get item from local storage before even storing it?

Tags: javascript, get, local-storage

Why in this code I am getting an item from `local storage` first even before storing it

```
let addnote = document.getElementById("addbtn");
addnote.addEventListener("click", saveNote );
let message = document.getElementById("notes2");
function saveNote() {
    let TXT = document.getElementById("addtxt");
    let note = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    console.log("save");
    if(note == 0){
        noteData2 = [];
    }
    else{
        noteData2 = JSON.parse(note);
    }
    noteData.push(TXT.value);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(noteData));
    TXT.value = "";
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't, then the second time you called `saveNote` you would overwrite the previous note instead of storing an array with two notes in it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining but unfortunately,
Didn't get it?
Can YOU please explain with an example or share some source where I can read about it?

Comment: I don't know what sort of example you are looking for. You described an example situation, I told you what would happen.

Comment: Because @Code_2 you're not "getting an item" you're getting _an array of items_ that you're adding a new item to, and then saving that.

Comment: Got it Thanks @Andy